# How to convert my byte[] methods to arraylist [] methods?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
int movedistance = 5; // Distance to move the board

@Override
public byte getLive(int x, int y) {
    return board[y][x];  // Arraylist board.get(y).get(x) ?
}

public void patternRight(){
        byte[][] testBoard = new byte[getHeight()][getWidth()];
        // testBoard = new Arraylist<> ? 
        for (int x = 0; x < getHeight(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < getWidth(); y++){
                if (getLive(y, x) == 1) testBoard[x][y + movedistance] = 1;
            }
        }
}
```

I'm trying to make a method that moves my game pattern on my board(Game of life). This move method I currently have works with byte[]. I want to make exactly same method but with ArrayList.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: why you want to use `ArrayList` to solve what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `byte[][]` with a `List<List<Byte>>` makes little sense, but here is how to do it.

First, though, your code is inconsistent with order of array indexes:

- `getLive()` parameters declared as `x,y`, but you call it with `if (getLive(y, x) == 1)`.
- In `getLive()`, you use `board[y][x]`, but then you use `testBoard[x][y + movedistance] = 1;`
- But you also use `getHeight()` with `x`, and `getWidth()` with `y`, so maybe it (accidentally?) "adds up".

I'll assume that method should always be `x,y`, array should be `[y][x]`, and that `x` is "width" and `y` is "height".

Also, `[y + movedistance]` will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since your loop uses full range of values. I'll assume you want to "wrap around" on overflow.

```
public byte getLive(int x, int y) {
    return board.get(y).get(x);
}

public void patternRight(){
    List<List<Byte>> testBoard = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++) {
        List<Byte> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++)
            row.add((byte) 0);
        testBoard.add(row);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++) {
            if (getLive(x, y) == 1)
                testBoard.get((y + movedistance) % getHeight()).set(x, (byte) 1);
        }
    }
}
```